# How to prevent SCons to clean specific part of build tree

Tags: scons

My project contains third-party library sources that located in separate directory:

```
/prj
    /src
        /app
        /lib1
        /lib2
        /third-party-lib
            SConscript
            ...
    SConstruct
```

Compiling of the third-party-lib is quite long because of large library size. I'm never change the sources of the library and the only case when the library needs to be rebuild is changes of the build options (compiler flags, for example).

To rebuild the project I issue commands:

```
scons -c && scons
```

In this case SCons removes all build products including the third-party-lib and subsequent build consumes a significant time due to third-party-lib compiling which, as said above, never changed. Method:

```
lib = env.StaticLibrary(Target, obj)
env.NoClean(lib)
```

does not give desired result - this preserves only final library file (lib.a) from clean. I've tried to preserve object files:

```
obj = env.Object(Sources)
env.NoClean(obj)
```

but this solves the problem only partially, because some object files compiled implicitly - the library code contains Qt code which processed by Qt meta-object compiler (MOC), therefore these object files do not included in 'obj' list.

Is there a way to prevent such third-part library rebuilding every time when the project rebuild carried out?

Comment: Do the MOC files show up with --tree=prune? If so then SCons knows about them and you can make them NoClean..  Perhaps using env.Glob?

Comment: Yes, you're right, SCons sees all nodes and 
'env.NoClean( env.Glob( '\*' + ProductName + '\*') )' 
'env.NoClean( lib )'
solves the problem, thank you!

Comment: I'll add as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The *SCons* way of doing things would be to **not** call "`scons -c`", but only

```
scons
```

if you want to rebuild your project.
It is *SCons* main strength to get all the dependencies (implicit and explicit) right, even for an iterative rebuild where only a handful of files have changed. By using the "`-c`" option, like you may be used from other build tools like "`make`", you're shortcutting this feature and creating problems where there would be none usually.

I assume that you're using your "`make clean; make all`" approach because you haven't properly defined all the dependencies in your project yet. Please do that first, it will help your build in the long run.

And no, there is no method that will prevent "cleaning" for a whole folder and its subdirs.

Comment: There are no problems with dependencies in my project, SCons builds targets correctly. The only thing that I want is ability to build project as "from scratch" sometimes. Besides, when build configuration is changed (for example, when removing some sources from 'Sources' list) there are possible "artefacts" - object files that are garbage. In this case directory tree needs to cleanup and rebuild.

Comment: Well, "from scratch" means "from scratch". `;)` You might want to consider splitting your current `SConstruct` in two: one for the third-party lib, and one for the actual project...

Comment: Fresh idea! I workarounded the issue with 'NoClean' + 'Glob' (see comment above), but separate SConstruct  for third-party libraries seems to be releable concept.

Answer (score 0):

Use env.Glob(), it will see files which SCons knows about but are not yet created when that logic is run.